# I'd like to apply voltage to the charging module with the converter I made

Tags: boost, charging

I would like to implement a charging system as a graduation project.

But I found that the logic of charging the battery pack is not that simple.

So I want to charge the charging module by applying voltage.

Here's the logic I'm thinking about

[image]

Also, the charging modules to be used are as follows.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/384008362604

Is there any problem with logic? Also, how should I calculate the equivalent load from the perspective of the boost converter when using the module? Thank you.

Comment: I-in is I-out*(Vout/Vin)